# Summing a trig series

Tags: summation

I am trying to sum the following expression:

```
(Cos[(2 π m)/N]^2 Cos[(2 π n)/ N])/(2 (Cos[(2 m π)/N] - Cos[(2 n π)/N]))
```

from `m=1` to `(N+1)/2` excluding the term `m=n`. I split this sum into two: the first from `m=1` to `n-1`, and the second from `m=n+1` to `(N+1)/2`.

I run into two problems: the first series just does not evaluate (*Mathematica* returns the expression). However when I plot it plugging in some values for `n`, `N` (with `N` always greater than `m`, `n`), I find the function to be well behaved in the interval.

The second series from `n+1` to `(N+1)/2` does sum, but it evaluates to complicated `QPolygamma` functions, and `FullSimplify` doesn't help. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please let me know if I need to modify the question to make it clearer etc.

Comment: Note that N is a special symbol in mathematica

Comment: @Chris: Good point, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I changed it to 'M' and the problem still remains.

Comment: Not every sum can be represented in a simple closed-form expression. Do you expect that to be the case here?

Comment: Using `n0` rather then `N`, if you split up the summand as a series of powers of `Cos[(2 \[Pi] m)/n0] - Cos[(2 n \[Pi])/n0]`, giving `(Cos[(2 \[Pi] n)/n0] (Cos[(2 \[Pi] m)/n0] - Cos[(2 n \[Pi])/n0]))/2 + Cos[(2 n \[Pi])/n0]^2 + Cos[(2 n \[Pi])/n0]^3/(2 (Cos[(2 m \[Pi])/n0] - Cos[(2 n \[Pi])/n0]))`, then Mathematica (version 9) can sum up (excluding `m = n`) the contribution from each power.